# change directory in unix shell (special characters)

Tags: bash, unix, cd

I have directory name starting with --. How to enter it with cd? Basic escape charaters is not working

```
# cd --smol--/
    -bash: cd: --: invalid option
    cd: usage: cd [-L|[-P [-e]]] [dir]

# cd \-\-smol\-\-
    -bash: cd: --: invalid option
    cd: usage: cd [-L|[-P [-e]]] [dir]

# cd  '--smol--'
    -bash: cd: --: invalid option
    cd: usage: cd [-L|[-P [-e]]] [dir]

# cd '\-\-smol\-\-'
    -bash: cd: \-\-smol\-\-: No such file or directory

# help
  GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `cd` like this:

```
cd -- '--smol--'
```

OR:

```
cd -- --smol--
```

Anything after `--` are not considered options for `cd` command.

Comment: Another workaround is to reference the directory: `cd ./--smol--` or the absolute path from root.

Answer (score 4):

You can prepend "./":

```
cd ./--smol--
```